# Grouping a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a huge NumPy array of size 778. I would like to pair the elements hence I'm using the following code to do so.

`coordinates = coordinates.reshape(-1, 2,2)`

However, if I use the following code it just works fine.

```
coordinates = coordinates[:len(coordinates)-1].reshape(-1, 2,2)
```

How can I do this in a proper way irrespective of the size?

Comment: `coordinates[:-1].reshape(-1, 2,2)`?

Comment: @Divakar, this would fail if array does not contain an even number of elements, this means that this can not be used irrespective of size.It can not be done irrespective of size, you will always have to check that you have even number of rows in your coordinates matrix, otherwise you will always end up with an element which can not be paired.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop It's based on the comment that `coordinates[:len(coordinates)-1].reshape(-1, 2,2)` works and OP wants something without that `len(coordinates)` dependency, at least it sounded like.

Comment: I would like to have it working without the dependency of `len(coordinates)`

Comment: I don't understand why and how `coordinates[:len(coordinates)-1].reshape(-1, 2,2)` works with `a huge NumPy array of size 778`. Sounds impossible to me.